# Android pass context to onclicklistener

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

Can anyone tell me how I can correctly pass my application context to my button setOnClickListener?

I'm attempting to scan barcodes when I click a "scan button" defined in my layout code using Zxing.

The following is my code:

```
    public class ScaningActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }
        });//close upload clicklistener

    final Button scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context c = getApplicationContext();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(c);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

    }//close onCreate
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
          IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
          if (scanResult != null) {
            // handle scan result
            Log.e("DATA", "TESTING SCAN RESULT : " + scanResult.toString());
          }else{
              Log.d("DATA", "NO SCAN RESULTS : ");// + scanResult.getFormatName());//scanResult.getContents());
          }

        }
}//close ScaningActivity
```

**The problem is *IntentIntegrator* does not recognise the *context* argument I am suppling as in the following:**

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(c);
```

Comment: Constructor takes an Activity not a Context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to replace

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();
```

by

```
Context c = ScaningActivity.this;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Context` you need to send yourActivityname or this:

`IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(Your_Activity_name Or this);`

Comment: `this` in the context of his source would return the current instance of `OnClickListener`, which is not an extension of `Context`. He would have to use `ScanningActivity.this` or pass in a `Context` through a constructor.